# question on how to skip an entire section, or a certain amount of lines

Tags: python-3.7

I'm quite new to python, and I'd like to know how to skip a section, or a certain amount of lines that are specified. If you explain how, PLEASE explain what does what because I won't know what it does if you don't. Thank you!

```
if tutoskip == "y" or tutoskip == "Y":
    pass

elif tutoskip == "n" or tutoskip == "N":
    pass
```

After this is a bunch of code that i'd like to skip if they decide to skip the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this code by just putting one conditional above the code you'd like to skip that checks if `tutoskip` is 'Y' or 'y'. calling `.lower()` on tutoskip ensures that either 'Y' or 'y' will allow the user skip the section. Note that `!=` is "not equal to"

```
if tutoskip.lower() != 'y':
    # Tutorial code to skip

# code that won't be skipped
```

Comment: Another thing, if I were to use ```.lower() !=``` again, how would I make it so it doesn't skip?

EDIT: Nevermind, found out how myself.